# Cannot Associate StackOverflow Account with SPSE

Tags: support, user-accounts

How can I do this? I have exhausted every menu option available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accounts are already associated. Here's a screenshot from your profile page on SharePoint:

[image: Proof of association]

Comment: How come my 5,300 votes are not included? We used to be able to do this? Is it not possible to login with my SO account??

Comment: That isn't how association works. This is a separate account entirely, but for having 200+ reputation on Stack Overflow, you do get a +100 bonus here on SharePoint. We're separate sites, with separate rules and all kinds of policy and scope kinks - so rather than thrust people with all the privileges representing experience on *other* sites, you keep the base every-day privileges like voting and commenting and have to spend some time in this site to earn all the advanced stuff like closing.

Comment: Thanks ccomet :)

Comment: Here's the link that shows all your associated accounts: http://stackexchange.com/users/1e519c57-8576-4676-9e14-59584e9e06c9?tab=accounts